# How can I convert input value?

Tags: reactjs, input, state

I have two inputs and want to convert the values, like area convertion.

```
let [input, setInput] = useState('');
let [inputs, setInputs] = useState('');



<div className="area_container">
     <input name="area_p" type="number" onChange={(e)=>{ setInput(e.target.value * 3.31) }} onFocus={() => {setInput('')}} value={inputs}/>
     <p>area</p>
     <input name="area_m" type="number" onChange={(e)=>{ setInputs(e.target.value / 3.31)}}  onFocus={() => {setInputs('')}} value={ input }/>
     <p>m<sup>2</sup></p>
</div>


// 1 area = 3.31 m2
```

So I want to use both inputs, but It's not working...

If I put the value in first input, the second input have a value which is converted automatically.
And  the opposite case is same, I hope.

How can I modify it? Please let me know...

Actually `onFocus` function is for "make input state value initially" but it's not working too.

Answer (score 0):

you need to assignment tow values

```
<input
  onChange={(e) => {
  setInput(e.target.value * 3.31)
  setInputs(e.target.value);
  }}
  value={inputs}
/>

<input
  onChange={(e) => {
  setInput(e.target.value);
  setInputs(e.target.value / 3.31);
  }}
  value={input}
/>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-template-forked-0wvum?file=/index.js)